# Why subclass may refer to anchestor fields while template subclass may not?

Tags: class, templates, g++

I see it is very uncomfortable to be obliged to use anchestor class fields by prefixing them with the anchestor class while this is not required normally, **"WHY IS THAT?"** and there is any solution ( while in the case bellow writting ::C is short, in real life cases the above takes at least one line of code, so it is not at all practical.

https://godbolt.org/z/E1sjxecYK

```
                        struct A        { int a=5;                  };
                        struct B:A      {           int b=a;        };

template<typename T>    struct C        { int c=7;                  };
template<typename T>    struct D:C<T>   {           int d=c;        };

/*
template<typename T>    struct E:C<T>   {           int d=C<T>::c;  };
*/

using namespace std;

int main(){
}
```